# Is it possible to filter a drop down list when not using a service?

Tags: orbeon

Using services and actions in Form Builder it is possible to have multilevel drop down lists (e.g., Region, District, Municipality) that are automatically filtered by selection. Is there currently any way to support this sort of functionality without using services?

I think the answer is no, but need to ask. This might fit under the open issue: "[FB: Actions independent from services](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1610)" and maybe in conjunction with the new [Datasets](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/datasets.html) feature. However, I am currently using 2016.2.1 so Datasets are not an option.

Comment: By "without services", are you referring specifically to the Form Builder *HTTP Services*, or in general to loading data by HTTP? Datasets don't avoid either, as the data in a dataset is loaded by calling an HTTP service. Also, would the [dynamic dropdown](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/dynamic-data-dropdown.html) help in this case?

Comment: @avernet I was referring to the form builder _HTTP Services_ but really I was looking for a way to do it without loading any data by HTTP. With the Datasets I was wondering if there might be a way to define a Dataset within the form definition rather than loading it via HTTP. The dynamic dropdown wouldn't help since it requires an HTTP service.

Comment: Currently, dataset are only populated by services. "Behind the scene", or not so "behind" ;), an instance is used, so you can could create the instance, following the naming convention expected by `fr:dataset()`, and use that function. But then, I'd recommend just using a normal instance, and accessing it with `instance()`. Would that make sense in your case?

Comment: Yes using `instance()` would make sense. But I'm not sure how to use it with the existing 2016.2.1 functionality. A dynamic dropdown can't use it because it only can use an HTTP service?